# Access environment variable set in template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Creating a simple template that sets an environment variable, then trying to read that variable from the job that extends it in the after_script section :

I am unable to read it, could i be doing something wrong?

I should be able to read it right ?

```
stages:
  - messing

.messing-1:
  script: export DUMMY=A

messing-2:
  stage: messing
  extends: .messing-1
  after_script:
    - echo $DUMMY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script

It has the following text about `after_script`:

> Are executed in a shell context separated from before_script and script scripts

I guess that this is what you are seeing here. If you change `messing-1` to use `before_script` and `messing-2` to use `script`, then I think it will work. The scripts should then be concatenated together.